# Excel Define Cell Name Using Office.JS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, office365, office-js

In Excel 365 app, how I can set the Name using excel 365 api at runtime ?  In [Dev.Office.com](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/nameditemcollection#relationships), they have provided read-only property to get the name.

**Background:**
Working on Excel Office 365 apps. We have a pre-define template and for every cell which we use in calculation have defined names for it.

I need to provide the functionality to add multiple cells based on user request(button click on task pane) and use these cells in calculation. I know how to add the field(cells) but stuck at defining the names. There is no way for us to evaluate the formula unless we use excel cell reference such as (B10, C24, etc) which we want to avoid.

Is there any other option to use like content control ?

Note : [This](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64#bmlearn_more_about_using_names) is I wanted to do using excel 365 api.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the names (named ranges and any other constants) are in fact read-only.  The good news is that we are in the process of implementing the named-range-addition/manipulation functionality.  Unless we run into unexpected difficulties, we should have it available in the coming months (likely as part of `ExcelApi 1.4` -- though again, no guarantees there, just an estimate if all goes to plan).